# Select2 - How to move the close icon to the right of the selected item

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using select2 for displaying a multiple selection component.  Instead of showing the close icon(x) to the left of the item, how can I move it to the right of the selected item?

Comment: You could probably use css to do that, but there is no code example in the question so idk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you add `float: right;` to the `.select2-selection__choice__remove` css class, this will set it on the right side.

EDIT: If you don't want to touch the select2 stylesheets, you can always use jquery and do something like this:

```
$('.select2').on('select2:open', function () {
  $('.select2-selection__choice__remove').addClass('select2-remove-right');
});
```

---

```
.select2-remove-right {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.select2-selection__choice__remove {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px /* I added to separate a little bit */
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can move the x using CSS only by adding in your css-File some code like this:

```
  .select2-container-multi .select2-search-choice-close {
    left: auto;
    right: 3px;
  }

  .select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-choice {
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in version 4.1.0

```
.select2-selection__choice {
     flex-direction: row-reverse!important;
}
```